# How to find an item's position and show in Python 3

Tags: python, list

I have a program and I would like to show the position of each letter, taking it from another file
File I'm getting the information from:

```
>sp|A1AA21|PEPT_ECOK1 Peptidase T OS=Escherichia coli O1:K1 / APEC OX=405955 GN=pepT PE=3 SV=1
MDKLLERFLNYVSLDTQSKAGVRQVPSTEGQWKLLHLLKEQLEEMGLINVTLSEKGTLMA
TLPANVPGDIPAIGFISHVDTSPDCSGKNVNPQIVENYRGGDIALGIGDEVLSPVMFPVL
HQLLGQTLITTDGKTLLGADDKAGIAEIMTALAVLQQKNIPHGDIRVAFTPDEEVGKGAK
HFDVDAFDARWAYTVDGGGVGELEFENFNAASVNIKIVGNNVHPGTAKGVMVNALSLAAR
IHAEVPADESPEMTEGYEGFYHLASMKGTVERADMHYIIRDFDRKQFEARKRKMMEIAKK
VGKGLHPDCYIELVIEDSYYNMREKVVEHPHILDIAQQAMRDCDIEPELKPIRGGTDGAQ
LSFMGLPCPNLFTGGYNYHGKHEFVTLEGMEKAVQVIVRIAELTAQRK
```

and I want to show the positions in the type:

```
A ------ 19,59,64...
B ------- -1
M --------  0,44,58...
```

esse é o código:

```
f = open('e.coli.fasta.txt','r')
sequencia = f.readlines()
amino = [] #para colocar o arquivo numa lista só com o texto de interresse 

for linha in sequencia:
  if linha.find('>') != 0:
    amino.append(linha)

tfasta= "".join(amino)

aminoacidos = {}
aminoacidos = {'A':'Alanina','B':'Ácido aspártico ou Asparagina','C':'Cisteína', 'D':'Ácido aspártico','E':'Ácido glutâmico','F':'Fenilalanina','G':'Glicina','H':'Histidina','I':'Isoleucina','J':'Leucina (L) ou Isoleucina','K':'Lisina','L':'Leucina','M':'Metionina','N':'Asparagina','O':'Pirrolisina','P':'Prolina','Q':'Glutamina','R':'Arginina','S':'Serina','T':'Treonina','U':'Selenocisteína','V':'Valina','W':'Triptofano','X':'qualquer','Y':'Tirosina'}

def ocorrencias(string):
  result = {}
  chaves = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
  for i in chaves:
    result[i] = tfasta.count(i)
  return result

ocor = ocorrencias(tfasta)

    index = 0
lista = []
while index < len(tfasta):
  index = tfasta.find('A',index)
  lista.append(index)
  if index == -1:
    break 
  index += 1

with open ('PeptidadeT-aminoacidos','w') as p:
  for i in range(65,90):
    a = ('%s' % (chr(i)))
    p.write('-{:4s}------{:5s}------{}\n'.format(a, aminoacidos[a], ocor[a]))
  for i in enumerate(lista):
    p.write('{}\n'.format(i))
```

Comment: Your code is counting the number of occurrences, not getting the positions.

Comment: I don't understand your sample output. I don't see `A` at positions 6 and 10 in the file.

Comment: I just gave an example in the positions

Comment: Why can't your example positions match the example input file, so we can understand the question better?

Comment: he has to count the number of occurrences and their positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a `positions` dictionary whose values are lists of indexes. Then loop through the text and append the indexes to the appropriate list.

```
positions = {}
for index, char in enumerate(tfasta):
    if char in positions:
        positions[char].append(index)
    else:
        positions[char] = [index]
print(positions)
```

Here's the full code:

```
with open('e.coli.fasta.txt','r') as f:
    sequencia = f.readlines()
amino = [] #para colocar o arquivo numa lista só com o texto de interresse 

for linha in sequencia:
    if linha.find('>') != 0:
        amino.append(linha)

tfasta= "".join(amino)

aminoacidos = {}
aminoacidos = {'A':'Alanina','B':'Ácido aspártico ou Asparagina','C':'Cisteína', 'D':'Ácido aspártico','E':'Ácido glutâmico','F':'Fenilalanina','G':'Glicina','H':'Histidina','I':'Isoleucina','J':'Leucina (L) ou Isoleucina','K':'Lisina','L':'Leucina','M':'Metionina','N':'Asparagina','O':'Pirrolisina','P':'Prolina','Q':'Glutamina','R':'Arginina','S':'Serina','T':'Treonina','U':'Selenocisteína','V':'Valina','W':'Triptofano','X':'qualquer','Y':'Tirosina'}

def ocorrencias(string):
    result = {}
    chaves = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
    for i in chaves:
        result[i] = tfasta.count(i)
        return result

ocor = ocorrencias(tfasta)

def positions(string):
    chaves = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'
    pos = {key: [] for key in chaves}
    for index, char in enumerate(string):
        if char in pos:
            pos[char].append(index)
    return pos

lista = positions(tfasta)

with open ('PeptidadeT-aminoacidos','w') as p:
  for i in range(65,90):
    a = ('%s' % (chr(i)))
    p.write('-{:4s}------{:5s}------{}\n'.format(a, aminoacidos[a], ocor[a]))
  for i in enumerate(lista):
    p.write('{}\n'.format(i))
```

Comment: is giving **KeyError: B**

Comment: probably by the letter B does not contain in the file

Comment: My second code snippet was using the wrong variable in one place, I just fixed it.

Comment: could you please put write code with this block? it's not working here

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Sorry, `key: 0` should have been `key: []`

Comment: continues to make mistakes in these lines, but now with *KeyError: \n* already tried to take the line break in p.write

Comment: You should use `amino.append(linha.strip())` to remove newlines.

Comment: I updated the answer to skip characters that aren't in `chaves`.

Comment: again this is giving error on line 36 with 'KeyError: B'

Comment: Line 36 is `for i in enumerate(lista)`?

Comment: the error was in a '"return'" that was not tabulated

Comment: now it's working, thank you very much, it saved my day hahaha